# How can I speed up git-tfs on large (10GB+) TFVC repos?

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, git-tfs

Some of our teams have large TFVC repos (10GB+, some > 100GB), and some with 5-10 years of history.  They are using git-tfs, but it can be very slow or not complete.

We have tried so far:

- Remove large binaries from the repo.
- Move dependencies to a package manager (like JFrog Artifactory).
- Take the recent repo/history from a specific changeset using git-tfs, then use ‘git-tfs pull’ to get the history from the changeset to today.
- For archive purposes, take the repo from older changesets using git-tfs and store somewhere for safekeeping.

Give our circumstances, what are the likely causes of this slowness, and what techniques can be used to speed things up?